# Am I liable for copyright infringements made by a non-affiliated source?

Tags: copyright

Let's say that I find a non-affiliated source that offers some creative work under a copyleft license and I decide to use that work, stating where I found it and under which license. If in the future that 3rd party gets sued for copyright infringement, can I be considered liable?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you used some creative work of mine without my permission (I'm the copyright holder, and you have no license giving you permission) then I can sue you to make you stop using my work, to get payment for damages, and to get payment for statutory damages. If you used my work because someone else told you wrongly that you had a license, that's very unfortunate for you, but is no reason why I wouldn't or shouldn't sue you.

Obviously in this situation that third party did something badly wrong. I can sue both of you together to make sure that I get payment from whoever has deeper pockets. You can also sue that third party if you think that their lying, or being mistaken, about a non-existing license  caused you damages, or if there is a contract or something that makes them responsible.

Comment: Yep, you can’t take my car either just because some rando said you could.

Comment: @DaleM I think the analogy is less "take your car", and more "am I liable if I purchased a car in good faith from a third-party, who misrepresented they had the rights to sell the car, but it actually was the case that the car was stolen from you (by the third party or someone else)".

Comment: However, if you rely on a third party's false assertion that they license my copyrights to you, and I sue you over your unlicensed use, then that may provide you grounds for suing the third party.

Comment: Note that suing the third party may or may not actually work, as many license statements explicitly disclaim any warranty of noninfringement (see for example the [MIT license](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)). But such disclaimers are not effective in all jurisdictions, so you might still be able to sue that third party anyway.

Comment: @Kevin: I also suspect that such a disclaimer wouldn't work against deliberately committing copyright infringement rather than inheriting it from a previous entity.

Comment: "is no reason why I wouldn't or shouldn't sue you." Certainly there's a moral reason. And there are public policy reasons to limit such suits.

Comment: @DaleM: If I purchase a car in good faith from someone who offers me a seemingly-valid title, but the car happens to be stolen, I would in most jurisdictions be required to forfeit the car, but if I make no attempt to prevent such forfeiture I wouldn't have any criminal culpability or civil liability beyond that.

Comment: @supercat: The equivalent of returning the car in this context is impoundment and destruction of the infringing works or copies. That can be one possible remedy for a copyright infringement lawsuit, although the law often (depending on jurisdiction) also provides for large statutory damage awards as well. It's important to remember that copyright law was designed under the assumption that large-scale, lawsuit-worthy copying would only be done by big companies, who could afford to exhaustively verify all of their copyright licenses and/or purchase insurance for them.

Comment: @Kevin: An additional complication is that in many cases companies would rather have people use their works in some ways without asking permission than have to either examine and respond to thousands of individual requests for permission to use work in minor ways or go on record as forbidding all such usages.  A lot of people post covers of songs on YouTube that receive less than 100 views.  The cost for a copyright holder to process a request to use the song in such a video would likely exceed any reasonable royalty that might be assessed for such a low viewership figure.

Comment: @supercat: There is already a process for licensing covers, at least under US law (mechanical/compulsory licensing), but for other uses I see your point.

Comment: @Kevin: The process for licensing covers would have a royalty of about a dime per *permanent* copy for works up to five minutes.  Compulsory licensing is limited to audio-only productions that either use the original song's lyrics or no lyrics at all, and don't combine any visuals.  These restrictions are most likely intended to prevent any unwanted association between the music and anything else, but if a YouTube cover simply shows a performer wearing neutral clothes singing in front of a neutral background, that should avoid any potentially-objectionable associations of the sorts...

Comment: ...over which copyright holders are intended to have veto authority.  If a video is likely to be viewed by fewer than ten different people, less than $1 of actual royalty would be required to give each of those people a permanent recording of the music.  The cost for a songwriter's agent to watch the video and ensure it was free of unwanted messages would almost certainly be greater than that.

Comment: I really dislike the analogy where copyright is equated to taking physical objects. Physical object cannot be duplicated, information can. To take the car as an analogy, copyright violation would be like waving a magic wand that produces another car identical to yours, and then selling that car. Your car remains untouched and you don't even know that anything has happened. And then you can go and sue the other person because they have a car that looks exactly like yours, but you don't like it that your car isn't unique anymore.

Comment: Vilx, my company pays me good money every month so I write software for them. And we don’t want to keep our software, we want to sell it. If you want to use software without paying, write it yourself. Ok, you don’t have to write it yourself. I’ll do it for you for £500 a day. Might go down to £475.